# robot_localization and IMU selection

Tags: imu, navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I am thinking to buy IMU to be used with robot_localization package. I understand that IMU must be in ENU mode. May I know which IMU support ENU mode and output reliable orientation information? Is microstrain 3DM-GX5-25 a good choice? But it is in NED. Can we use it as ENU via some kind of static transform?
http://www.microstrain.com/inertial/3DM-GX5-25

Best Regards
Min Latt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269565/robot_localization-and-imu-selection/) by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you working from source? Even if you get an NED IMU, it's easy enough to modify drivers to convert to ENU. I typically just invert the values for the Y and Z axes.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-10-08**:
Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer.